# Gradle: No tests found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-testing

When I am trying to run Android tests by executing:

```
./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

The following error occurs:

```
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[devicename] FAILED
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I **have not made any changes** to `build.gradle` or `gradle-wrapper.properties` files.

The issue can't be solved by updating everything to the latest version (gradle, android plugin, build tools, etc.)

All tests were previously successful. What could cause this mystic regression? Thanks.

Comment: It sometimes happens to me too, which means it's time to clean project.

Comment: @azizbekian the funny thing is that nothing has changed. I cleaned the project several times.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

One possible reason for this error message is that you get a crash in the app early in the test Runner. In such cases the exception stack will be in logcat but not in the gradle output.

Comment: Indeed, this was the case. Thank you!

Comment: @Miguel you are right. This crash seems random, it happens sometimes but not all the time with no condition changes. Any way to ensure it doesn't happen at all?

Answer (score 6):

I had the issue, try upgrading the test runner. Upgrading it to 0.5 from 0.4.x solved it. Ensure you have these lines in your build.gradle:

```
androidTestCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:0.5"
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this exact issue today. Please do feel free to use all the other worthy solutions as mentioned above but what specifically worked for me was to delete the ".gradle" folder (found under the project panel on the left in Android Studio) entirely, followed by a clean build. A simple clean build didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the tests are placed in the `test` or `androidTest` directory without a package. The path should be something like `/src/androidTest/kotlin/yourPackageName/yourTestClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if individually, all tests pass. Could be some test(s) is(are) failing. Had a similar issue and that was my case

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error like this, it also shows 'running 0 test on (name of my emulator)'
This is because my emulator was using API 34, while in the build.gradle, the targetSdk is 30, minSdk is 27.
So I changed my emulator API to 30, by clicking the little pen icon on the device management panel and edit the emulator API

Answer (score -3):

I solved this by deleting androidTests folders from unneeded modules - /common and /data in my case.

Comment: Deleting the tests is not a solution