# espresso-contrib 3.3.0 works fine but any newer version results in build failures

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

We have defined the dependency `androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0")`.
Instrumentation tests are working fine.
But when we try to update to a newer version (e.g. 3.4.0 or 3.5.0) we got the following error:

```
Instrumentation did not complete:
Instrumentation code: 0
Instrumentation result bundle: 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDevShortTimeoutDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at:
```

The report shows the following:
[image: Test Summary]

I've found [Android Tests: No tests found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949416/android-tests-no-tests-found) and [Gradle: No tests found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041775/gradle-no-tests-found) but none pointed me to a solution.

The following androidTestImplementation dependencies are used:

```
androidTestImplementation(project(":sharedTest"))
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.5.0")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.5.0")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.4")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0")
androidTestImplementation("com.microsoft.appcenter:espresso-test-extension:1.5")
androidTestImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockitoTestVersion")
androidTestImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0")
androidTestUtil("androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.2")
```

Does anyone has a hint or by any chance a solution?

Comment: Did find any solution to this?

Comment: Nope, sry. Still unsolved...

Comment: Just as a reference: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Logcat for errors. I had a Firebase initialization error caused by the `protobuf-lite` update in Espresso 3.4.0. You need to exclude this module from `espresso-contrib`.

```
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1') {
    exclude module: 'protobuf-lite'
}
```

You may need to exclude that also from any other dependency that internally depends on `espresso-contrib`. You can do that using:

```
configurations {
    androidTestImplementation.exclude module: 'protobuf-lite'
}
```